# How to express a project dependency in a Gradle plugin?

Tags: kotlin, gradle, plugins, gradle-plugin

I'm writing a Gradle plugin, and I want to add some dependencies on other projects. How do I express that in the plugin code?

For normal dependencies, it's `project.dependencies.add("implementation", "my.dependency.name")`

In the Gradle Kotlin DSL, I would do

```
    implementation(kotlin("stdlib-jdk8"))
    implementation(project(":myproject"))
```

How do I express those two in my plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Gradle Build Language Reference](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/index.html) documentation we can see:

> ### Some basics
>
> There are a few basic concepts that you should understand, which will help you write Gradle scripts.
>
> First, Gradle scripts are *configuration scripts*. As the script executes, it configures an object of a particular type. **For example, as a build script executes, it configures an object of type `Project`** *[emphasis added]*. This object is called the *delegate object* of the script. *[...]*

This tells us that when you use `project(":myproject")` in the build script you are actually invoking [`Project#project(String)`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#project-java.lang.String-). With that in mind, you should be able to simply use the same method in your plugin implementation:

```kotlin
project.dependencies.add("implementation", project.project(":myproject"))
```

The `kotlin("stdlib-jdk8")` is a little more complicated, but not by much. When you use that "syntax" you're actually invoking the [`DependencyHandler.kotlin`](https://gradle.github.io/kotlin-dsl-docs/api/org.gradle.kotlin.dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.dsl.-dependency-handler/kotlin.html) extension function. You get a `DependencyHandler` instance when you invoke `project.dependencies`. However, to make that extension function available to your plugin code you need to add the Kotlin DSL API to your *plugin's* dependencies. This is made easier with the [Kotlin DSL Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html#sec:kotlin-dsl_plugin):

```kotlin
plugins {
    `kotlin-dsl`
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}
```

Altogether, your plugin code might look something like:

```kotlin
import org.gradle.api.Plugin
import org.gradle.api.Project
import org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.kotlin

class FooPlugin : Plugin<Project> {

    override fun apply(target: Project) {
        // Apply plugin which adds "implementation" configuration?
        target.dependencies.apply {
            add("implementation", target.project(":myproject"))
            add("implementation", kotlin("stdlib-jdk8"))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I had to change the plugin invocation to `id("org.gradle.kotlin.kotlin-dsl") version "1.3.6"`, but then it worked. Thanks again!