# How to call kover DependencyHandler extension from a Gradle custom plugin?

Tags: kotlin, gradle-plugin, kover

I'm building a custom Gradle plugin to apply [Kover](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx-kover) plugin to multiple projects.
To generate a Kover report from multiple subprojects, I need to add a dependency to the root project, according to the docs:

```
dependencies {
  kover(project(":another:project"))
}
```

I'm trying to access that `kover` extension in my custom Gradle plugin but I can't find a way to make it work.
Can you please let me know how to define that dependency in my Gradle `Plugin.apply()` method?

I tried following [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63068879), but I can't find the extension `kover` to import in my Gradle code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
val configurations: Configuration = project.configurations.getByName(KoverNames.DEPENDENCY_CONFIGURATION_NAME)
configurations.dependencies.add(project.dependencies.create(project.project("my-subproject")))
```